# Shall REST API Design pay Respect to Inheritance?

Tags: rest, flask, api-design

This is more of a question regarding design rather than implementation. I have been working on a personal application with Python Flask backend and Vue.js SPA frontend for quite some time now and am now a bit puzzled on how to design the actual REST API.

My backend heavily depends on inheritance, e.g. there's the broad notion of an `Account` and then there is the `ManagedAccount`, exhibiting all properties of the former but also additional ones. Then there are `Transactions`, `PredictedTransactions`, `RecurringTransactions` etc., I guess you get the gist.

I read up on REST API design beforehand, e.g. [on the Overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/) and before I was working with IDs, I had the following design:

```
/accounts/         [GET]  - returns all Accounts including ManagedAccounts with Account-specific properties
/accounts/managed/ [GET]  - returns all ManagedAccounts with ManagedAccount-specific properties
/accounts/         [POST] - creates a new Account
/accounts/managed/ [POST] - creates a new ManagedAccount
```

Now, this worked quite well until I introduced ID-dependent functions, e.g.

```
/accounts/<:id>         [PATCH]  - modifies the received data in Account with given ID, can also be used to alter Account-specific properties in ManagedAccounts
/accounts/managed/<:id> [PATCH]  - modifies the received data in ManagedAccount with given ID
/accounts/<:id>         [DELETE] - deletes an Account, can also be used for ManagedAccount
```

For all IDs I am using RFC4122-compliant UUIDs in version 4, so there definitely will never be a collision within the route. Still, this behavior triggers an assertion error with Flask, which can be circumvented, but got me to rather double-check whether this design approach has any pitfalls I have not yet considered.

Two alternatives came to my mind:

- Segregating the parent classes under a separate path, e.g. using `/accounts/all/` for `Account`. This requires knowing the inheritance depth beforehand (e.g. would need breaking changes if I were to introduce a class inheriting from `ManagedAccount`).
- Not incorporating inheritance in the routes, e.g. using `/managed_accounts/` or `/accounts_managed/`. This would be the easiest method implementation-wise, but would - in my opinion - fail to give an accurate representation of the data model.

From the beginning on I want to give this API consistent guarantees as defined in the backend data model, e.g. for the `Transaction` I can currently assure that `/transactions/executed/` and `/transactions/predicted/` return mutually exclusive sets that, when joined, equal that returned by `/transactions/`.

Right now I am able to effectively utilize this on front-end side, e.g. poll data from `Account` in general and get specifics for `ManagedAccount` when required. Is the design I am currently pursuing  a 'good' REST API design or am I clinging to concepts that are not applicable in this domain? If so, which design approach would make more sense and especially, why and in what situations would it be beneficial to the current one?

Answer (score 0):

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your URI, so long as your identifiers are consistent with the production rules defined in RFC 3986.

```
/d501c2c2-5729-469c-8eed-3643e1b06504
```

That UUID, of itself, is a perfectly satisfactory identifier for REST purposes.

> This is more of a question regarding design

Yes, exactly -- the *machines* don't care what spellings you use for your resource identifiers, which gives you some freedom to address other concerns.  The usual choice here is to make them easier for humans (easier for people to implement, easier for people to document, easier for operators to recognize in a log... lots of possibilities).

"No ambiguities in our automated routing" is a perfectly reasonable design constraint.

Path segments are used for the hierarchical parts of an identifier.  There's no particular reason, however, that your identifier hierarchy needs to be aligned with "inheritance" hierarchy.

One long standing design principle on the web is that [Cool URI Don't Change](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI); so before introducing inheritance cues in your identifiers, be sure to consider how stable your inheritance design is.